# Error sending message to RabbitMQ endpoint with WSO2 Micro Integrator

Tags: rabbitmq, wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I am using WSO2 Micro Integrator to send messages to a RabbitMQ endpoint. However, I am getting the following error message:

> The system cannot infer the transport information from the
> rabbitmq:/localhost:5672/rabbitqueue?rabbitmq.client.connection.retry.count=5&rabbitmq.message.content.type=application/json&rabbitmq.connection.username=guest&rabbitmq.connection.password=guest&rabbitmq.connection.virtual.host=/
> URL.

I have configured the endpoint correctly and ensured that the RabbitMQ server is running. Here is the relevant section of my configuration:

```
<endpoint name="rabbitmq-endpoint">
  <address uri="rabbitmq:/localhost:5672/rabbitqueue?rabbitmq.client.connection.retry.count=5&amp;rabbitmq.message.content.type=application/json&amp;rabbitmq.connection.username=guest&amp;rabbitmq.connection.password=guest&amp;rabbitmq.connection.virtual.host=/" />
</endpoint>
```

MessageStore,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messageStore class="org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.rabbitmq.RabbitMQStore" name="message-store" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.host.name">localhost</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.producer.guaranteed.delivery.enable">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.host.port">5672</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.route.key"/>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.username">guest</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.virtual.host">/</parameter>
    <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.ssl.enabled">false</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.exchange.name"/>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.queue.name">rabbitqueue</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.rabbitmq.password">guest</parameter>
</messageStore>
```

Message Processor,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messageProcessor class="org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ScheduledMessageForwardingProcessor" messageStore="message-store" name="message-processor" targetEndpoint="rabbitmq-endpoint" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameter name="client.retry.interval">1000</parameter>
    <parameter name="max.delivery.attempts">4</parameter>
    <parameter name="member.count">1</parameter>
    <parameter name="message.processor.reply.sequence">repseq</parameter>
    <parameter name="message.processor.fault.sequence">faultseq</parameter>
    <parameter name="store.connection.retry.interval">1000</parameter>
    <parameter name="max.store.connection.attempts">-1</parameter>
    <parameter name="max.delivery.drop">Disabled</parameter>
    <parameter name="interval">1000</parameter>
    <parameter name="is.active">true</parameter>
</messageProcessor>
```

Full stack trace,

> [2023-05-02 16:13:49,900]  INFO {RabbitMQStore} - Store
> [message-store] Successfully connected to RabbitMQ Broker [2023-05-02
> 16:13:49,916] ERROR {ClientUtils} - The system cannot infer the
> transport information from the
> rabbitmq:/localhost:5672/rabbitqueue?rabbitmq.client.connection.retry.count=5&rabbitmq.message.content.type=application/json&rabbitmq.connection.username=guest&rabbitmq.connection.password=guest&rabbitmq.connection.virtual.host=/
> URL. [2023-05-02 16:13:49,918]  WARN {EndpointContext} - Endpoint :
> rrabbitmq:/localhost:5672/rabbitqueue?rabbitmq.client.connection.retry.count=5&rabbitmq.message.content.type=application/json&rabbitmq.connection.username=guest&rabbitmq.connection.password=guest&rabbitmq.connection.virtual.host=/
> will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed [2023-05-02 16:13:49,918]  WARN
> {EndpointContext} - Suspending endpoint : rabbitmq-endpoint with
> address
> rabbitmq:/localhost:5672/rabbitqueue?rabbitmq.client.connection.retry.count=5&rabbitmq.message.content.type=application/json&rabbitmq.connection.username=guest&rabbitmq.connection.password=guest&rabbitmq.connection.virtual.host=/
>
> - current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Tue May 02 16:14:19 IST 2023 [2023-05-02 16:13:49,919] ERROR
>   {ForwardingService} - [ message-processor ] Error while forwarding
>   message to endpoint rabbitmq-endpoint.
>   org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Error sending Message to the
>   endpoint
>   at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService.tryToDispatchToEndpoint(ForwardingService.java:623)
>   at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService.dispatch(ForwardingService.java:542)
>   at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService.execute(ForwardingService.java:247)
>   at org.wso2.micro.integrator.mediation.ntask.NTaskAdapter.execute(NTaskAdapter.java:105)
>   at org.wso2.micro.integrator.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:63)
>   at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
>   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport
>   information from the
>   rabbitmq:/localhost:5672/rabbitqueue?rabbitmq.client.connection.retry.count=5&rabbitmq.message.content.type=application/json&rabbitmq.connection.username=guest&rabbitmq.connection.password=guest&rabbitmq.connection.virtual.host=/
>   URL.
>   at org.apache.axis2.description.ClientUtils.inferOutTransport(ClientUtils.java:86)
>   at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.prepareMessageContext(OperationClient.java:288)
>   at org.apache.axis2.description.OutOnlyAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutOnlyAxisOperation.java:249)
>   at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
>   at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.sendRobust(BlockingMsgSender.java:503)
>   at org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender.send(BlockingMsgSender.java:380)
>   at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.send(Axis2FlexibleMEPClient.java:102)
>   at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendOn(Axis2Sender.java:86)
>   at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.send(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:586)
>   at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.send(AbstractEndpoint.java:409)
>   at org.apache.synapse.endpoints.AddressEndpoint.send(AddressEndpoint.java:77)
>   at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService.tryToDispatchToEndpoint(ForwardingService.java:619)
>   ... 10 more
>
> [2023-05-02 16:13:49,921] ERROR {ForwardingService} -
> BlockingMessageSender of message processor [message-processor] failed
> to forward message to endpoint rabbitmq-endpoint [2023-05-02
> 16:13:49,922] ERROR {ForwardingService} - Message processor
> [message-processor] failed to send the message to client
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService.sendThroughFaultSeq(ForwardingService.java:792)
> at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService.handleFailedInvocations(ForwardingService.java:690)
> at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService.tryToDispatchToEndpoint(ForwardingService.java:678)
> at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService.dispatch(ForwardingService.java:542)
> at org.apache.synapse.message.processor.impl.forwarder.ForwardingService.execute(ForwardingService.java:247)
> at org.wso2.micro.integrator.mediation.ntask.NTaskAdapter.execute(NTaskAdapter.java:105)
> at org.wso2.micro.integrator.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:63)
> at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

I am not sure what could be causing this issue. Can someone please suggest possible solutions to resolve this error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added following config to enable RabbitmQ sender in the `deployment.toml`

```ini
[transport.rabbitmq]
sender_enable = true
```

The most common reason for this error is not enabling the transport sender configs, since you confirmed it's already enabled. Try changing the connection URL to the below format.

```xml
<address uri="rabbitmq:/AMQPProducerSample?rabbitmq.server.host.name=localhost&amp;rabbitmq.server.port=5672&amp;rabbitmq.queue.name=queue&amp;rabbitmq.queue.route.key=route&amp;rabbitmq.exchange.name=exchange"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But yes, I have enabled both `sender_enable` and `listener_enable` in the file `deployment.toml` but still not working.

Comment: @SomeGuy are you using Integration Studio to start the server?

Comment: No, I am starting MI separately. Not through the studio.

Comment: @SomeGuy what is the MI version you are using?

Comment: @SomeGuy Do you get the `RABBITMQ Sender started` info log when you start the MI server?

Comment: @ycr I am using MI 4.0.0 version.

Comment: @sanoJ Yes I see it. I see both of these `RABBITMQ Sender started` and `RabbitMQ AMQP Transport Sender initialized...`

Comment: @SomeGuy check the update in the answer.

Comment: @ycr I tried but unfortunately I am still getting that error.

Comment: @SomeGuy can you share the full error stack as well?

Comment: @sanoJ I updated the question by adding the full stack trace.